How to prove that $f = 0$ almost everywhere given vanishing Lebesgue integrals over all subintervals?
I am trying to solve the following problem:
Since $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, it is Lebesgue measurable.
Let $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue integrable function such that for all subintervals $(a, b) \subset [0, 1]$, we have
$
\int_a^b f \, \mathrm{d}m = 0.
$
How can I deduce that $f = 0$ Lebesgue almost everywhere?
Here is my reasoning so far:

If $a = b$, then clearly
$
\int_{(a, a)} f \, \mathrm{d}m = \int_{\emptyset} f\, \mathrm{d}m = 0.
$

Now, suppose $f \neq 0$ and $m((a, b)) > 0$. Then there exists some subinterval $(a, b) \subset [0, 1]$ with $m((a, b)) > 0$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in (a, b)$.


However, I’m stuck at this point. I cannot directly write $(a, b) = \{x \in [0, 1]: f(x) > \epsilon\}$, since we cannot always find intervals in measurable sets.
How do I proceed from here? Is there an alternative argument or technique that I can use to arrive at the conclusion?

You set with epsilon is interesting, maybe use one of its connected components. If it is not négligeable then it will have a non trivial intérior.

You can't say that an interval $(a,b)$ exists with $f\neq 0$ there; for example $f$ could be $0$ on the irrationals and $1$ elsewhere. But by definition of not zero-almost-everywhere $A = {x: f(x) \neq 0}$ does not have measure $0$.  If  every set ${x: f(x) > \epsilon}$ had measure $0$, then $A = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty {x: f(x) > 1/n}$ would also have measure $0$ by subadditivity. I'm assuming $f \geq 0$ here (you can reduce to this case.)

This question is similar to: Let $m$ be Lebesgue measure and $a \in R$. Suppose that $f : R \to R$ is integrable, and $\int_a^xf(y) , dy = 0$ for all $x$. Then $f = 0$ a.e.. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You already know that if $f \neq 0$, there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $\lambda(\{f\ge \epsilon\}) >0$ otherwise we would have $ 0= \lambda \left( \bigcup_{n} \{f\ge 1/n\} \right)= \lambda(\{ f>0\})$ which is absurd.
We now consider $\bigsqcup_{ x \in X} I_x$ its connected components. We have
$$0 < \lambda \left( \bigsqcup_{ x \in X} I_x \right) = \sum_{ x \in X} \lambda( I_x)$$

we can deal with such sums since everything is positive! For a positive family $(a_j)_{j \in J}$, we have
$$\sum_{j \in J} a_j := \sup_{ K \in \mathcal P_f (J) } \sum_{k \in K} a_k$$
where $\mathcal P_f$ denotes the finite parts.
As a matter of fact is such a sum is finite, only a countable number of summands are non zero.

This means that necessarily we have some $x_0 \in X$ such that $\lambda(I_{x_0})>0$ which means (since $I_{x_0}$ is an interval that the open interval $I = \operatorname{int} ( I_{x_0})$ has a non zero measure.
We deduce
$$ \int_I f \ge \int_I \epsilon = \lambda(I) \epsilon >0$$
Which is absurd.
